# AS3 Warning message excess bytes

Tags: actionscript-3, warnings

When I publish my flash files, I get this message:

> `WARNING: excess bytes: -616, Tag: DefineFont3, Index: 5`
>   `WARNING: excess bytes: 2, Tag: DefineFont3, Index: 36`

What are these warning? Anything related to these warning?

Yesterday is still fine, but today I get this.

Comment: DefineFont is a tag inside SWF file with embedded font data. Seems like SWF is corrupted...

Comment: Seem like after I remove all the text field then is OK already. Need to replace all the text field manually again only can solve this warning message.

Comment: Are you by chance using a SWFTimeline.as package? [SWFTimeline.as on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/katopz/source/browse/trunk/as3/labs/as3swf/src/com/codeazur/as3swf/SWFTimeline.as?spec=svn1322&r=1322) This is all I could find doing research to help - perhaps it'll get you somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of your libraries are using the SWFTimeline. It's source code contains the very same warning.

The following code snippet is from the SWFTimeline.as file, starting at line 84.

```
 // Adjust position (just in case the parser under- or overflows)
   if(data.position != pos + tagHeader.tagLength) {
      trace("WARNING: excess bytes: " + 
         (data.position - (pos + tagHeader.tagLength)) + ", " +
         "Tag: " + tag.name + ", " +
         "Index: " + (tags.length - 1)
      );
      data.position = pos + tagHeader.tagLength;
   }
```

It seens to be caused by malformed tags or file corruptions, maybe other reasons too.